# kube-state-metrics - Failed to list *v1.Pod: serializer for text/html; charset=utf-8 doesn't exist

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I'm trying to setup a monitoring of our Kubernetes cluster but it's not that easy. In the first time I tried on a dedicated VM to scrap all metrics following configs I can find on Internet and prometheus.io but I read several time it's not the best way to do it. I found a suggestion to use [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics), it's done, the pod is running and metrics are reachable from outside (Azure infra). so http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/metrics is showing me a correct result.

When I add this to the config:

```
- job_name: 'Kubernetes-Nodes'
  scheme: http
  #tls_config:
    #insecure_skip_verify: true
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - api_server: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080'
    role: endpoints
    namespaces:
      names: [default]
    #tls_config:
      #insecure_skip_verify: true
    bearer_token: %VERYLONGLINE%
  relabel_configs:
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_namespace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_name
```

The log I can find is :

```
Sep 25 06:53:59 monitoring001 prometheus[59005]: level=error ts=2018-09-25T06:53:59.636669498Z caller=main.go:234 component=k8s_client_runtime err="github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:288: Failed to list *v1.Pod: serializer for text/html; charset=utf-8 doesn't exist"
```

Anyone has an idea ?

Thank you,

Comment: Where is your Prometheus located? And if it is in the same Kubernetes cluster, are you trying to reach API-server server using local or external IP address? Do you use any authorization for that?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the issue ! My Prometheus is located on a dedicated VM outside Kubernetes cluster.

Kube-state-metrics is exposing metrics from an IP outside of the cluster,because of this, it's not necessary to scrap metrics like a kubernetes object, it's just necessary to scrap metrics like a simple target